# Retrigger SSIS package via SQL Agent

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS ETL where I need to it to automatically restart on completion as it’s constantly expecting new files to arrive. However,  I don’t want an instance continuously running on a loop.

My idea was to use the Execute SQL Agent task before the last package completes but I’ve tested this out and I get an error saying the SQL agent job can’t be started by the same user that has an active job still running.

I’m looking for some advice on the best way to retrigger the SQL agent job. I was thinking of creating a separate job which I would execute to start the desired job - I’m thinking there must be a better way of doing it though.

Any advice or pointers welcome.

Thanks

Comment: What is your maximum allowable delay between a file arriving and when the SSIS package should begin execution. Is there a semi defined window for which the file should arrive? Is there any concern that the delivery of the file might be detected but the complete file has not been delivered (think multi-gb source files delivered via FTP)

Comment: The files need to be consumed withing 2 minutes of arriving. What I didn’t mention is that I have implemented a loop container which executes a Directory.GetFiles method. This executes every 2 minutes upto a specified timeout limit. If a file arrives / exists, it executes the ETL packages - following this I want the job to auto-restart. If the loop times-out, let’s say at midnight, the package would be restarted at 6am by the scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't want the SSIS package to run constantly in a loop, you can schedule the SQL Agent job to run every 10 seconds. That's the most frequently I am able to schedule a job. If the previous run of a job is still going 10 seconds later, then it won't start another instance of the package. Once it completes, it will start it again 10 seconds later.

Comment: Legit strategy. Keep in mind, though, that there are about 2-4 seconds of overhead just in firing up/shutting down a package, so if you haven't already, I'd recommend an initial step in your package that checks to see if a file exists and shuts the package down if there isn't at least one there. That'll minimize runtime so the instances aren't stepping on each other when there's nothing there to process.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had thought about this but not keen on it as an approach as it would result it lots of unnecessary log entries in my audit tables. I want to be able to control the retrigger of the package following completion of the ETL process.

Answer (score 0):

I put together a post on [Polling in SQL Agent](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2018/10/polling-in-sql-agent.html) This query checks every 5 seconds for a file up to a maximum of 60 seconds (all configurable)

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- http://www.patrickkeisler.com/2012/11/how-to-use-xpdirtree-to-list-all-files.html
DECLARE
    -- Don't do stupid things like adding spaces into folder names
    @sourceFolder varchar(260) = 'C:\ssisdata\Input'
    -- Have to use SQL matching rules, not DOS/SSIS
,   @fileMask sysname = 'SourceData%.txt'
    -- how long to wait between polling
,   @SleepInSeconds int = 5
    -- Don't exceed 24 hours aka 86400 seconds
,   @MaxTimerDurationInSeconds int = (3600 * 0) + (60 * 1) + 0
    -- parameter for xp_dirtree 0 => top folder only; 1 => subfolders
,   @depth int = 1
    -- parameter for xp_dirtree 0 => directory only; 1 => directory and files
,   @collectFile int = 1
,   @RC bigint = 0;

-- Create a table variable to capture the results of our directory command
DECLARE
    @DirectoryTree table
(
    id int IDENTITY(1, 1)
,   subdirectory nvarchar(512)
,   depth int
,   isFile bit
);

-- Use our sleep in seconds time to generate a delay time string
DECLARE
    @delayTime char(10) = CONVERT(char(10), TIMEFROMPARTS(@SleepInSeconds/60 /60, @SleepInSeconds/60, @SleepInSeconds%60, 0, 0), 108)
,   @stopDateTime datetime2(0) = DATEADD(SECOND, @MaxTimerDurationInSeconds, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

-- Force creation of the folder
EXECUTE dbo.xp_create_subdir @sourceFolder;

-- Load the results of our directory
INSERT INTO
    @DirectoryTree
(
    subdirectory
,   depth
,   isFile
)
EXECUTE dbo.xp_dirtree
    @sourceFolder
,   @depth
,   @collectFile;

-- Prime the pump
SELECT
    @RC = COUNT_BIG(1)
FROM
    @DirectoryTree AS DT
WHERE
    DT.isFile = 1
    AND DT.subdirectory LIKE @fileMask;

WHILE @rc = 0 AND @stopDateTime > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
BEGIN

    -- Load the results of our directory
    INSERT INTO
        @DirectoryTree
    (
        subdirectory
    ,   depth
    ,   isFile
    )
    EXECUTE dbo.xp_dirtree
        @sourceFolder
    ,   @depth
    ,   @collectFile;

    -- Test for file existence
    SELECT
        @RC = COUNT_BIG(1)
    FROM
        @DirectoryTree AS DT
    WHERE
        DT.isFile = 1
        AND DT.subdirectory LIKE @fileMask;

    IF @RC = 0
    BEGIN
        -- Put our process to sleep for a period of time
        WAITFOR DELAY @delayTime;
    END
END

-- at this point, we have either exited due to file found or time expired
IF @RC > 0
BEGIN
    -- Take action when file was found
    PRINT 'Go run SSIS or something';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- Take action for file not delivered in expected timeframe
    PRINT 'Naughty, naughty';
END
```

To address your specific needs, maybe set the job up like this.

1. Create a job
2. Add to the job server
3. Create the polling job step. On failure, retry in 2 minutes for a max of 30 times (alter this as need be)
4. Create an SSIS running step
5. Define a job schedule that runs every 2 minutes from 6 A.M. to midnight

At this point, we have belts, braces, and suspenders here. The job starts every 2 minutes. In the event the job is already running, nothing bad happens. Once the job begins, it noodles around looking for the file. If it times out, it raises an exception (your TODO) which causes the agent job to wait 2 minutes and then retry up to 30 times.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job
    @job_name = N'SQL Agent 2 minutes max'
,   @enabled = 1
,   @notify_level_eventlog = 0
,   @notify_level_email = 2
,   @notify_level_page = 2
,   @delete_level = 0
,   @category_name = N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
,   @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT;

SELECT
    @jobId;
GO

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver
    @job_name = N'SQL Agent 2 minutes max'
,   @server_name = N'.\DEV2014';
GO

USE msdb;
GO

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep
    @job_name = N'SQL Agent 2 minutes max'
,   @step_name = N'Polling'
,   @step_id = 1
,   @cmdexec_success_code = 0
,   @on_success_action = 3
,   @on_fail_action = 2
,   @retry_attempts = 30
,   @retry_interval = 2
,   @os_run_priority = 0
,   @subsystem = N'TSQL'
,   @command = N'SELECT 1 AS PasteInTheFullQuery'
,   @database_name = N'master'
,   @flags = 0;
GO

USE msdb;
GO

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep
    @job_name = N'SQL Agent 2 minutes max'
,   @step_name = N'Run SSIS'
,   @step_id = 2
,   @cmdexec_success_code = 0
,   @on_success_action = 1
,   @on_fail_action = 2
,   @retry_attempts = 0
,   @retry_interval = 0
,   @os_run_priority = 0
,   @subsystem = N'SSIS'
,   @command = N'/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\Demo\ProjectDeploymentModel\Package2.dtsx\"" /SERVER "\".\dev2014\"" /Par "\"$ServerOption::LOGGING_LEVEL(Int16)\"";1 /Par "\"$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)\"";True /CALLERINFO SQLAGENT /REPORTING E'
,   @database_name = N'master'
,   @flags = 0;
GO

USE msdb;
GO

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job
    @job_name = N'SQL Agent 2 minutes max'
,   @enabled = 1
,   @start_step_id = 1
,   @notify_level_eventlog = 0
,   @notify_level_email = 2
,   @notify_level_page = 2
,   @delete_level = 0
,   @description = N''
,   @category_name = N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
,   @notify_email_operator_name = N''
,   @notify_page_operator_name = N'';
GO

USE msdb;
GO

DECLARE @schedule_id int;

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule
    @job_name = N'SQL Agent 2 minutes max'
,   @name = N'Every 2 minutes'
,   @enabled = 1
,   @freq_type = 4
,   @freq_interval = 1
,   @freq_subday_type = 4
,   @freq_subday_interval = 2
,   @freq_relative_interval = 0
,   @freq_recurrence_factor = 1
,   @active_start_date = 20181018
,   @active_end_date = 99991231
,   @active_start_time = 60000
,   @active_end_time = 235959
,   @schedule_id = @schedule_id OUTPUT;

SELECT
    @schedule_id;
GO
```